# Get quadratic function coefficients from height of the curve and distance between roots

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

I'm developing a game where fish will jump out of the water, following a quadratic curve (red in the image below).

In my code, assuming the water level is `y=0`, I have three variables: the width `w` of the jump (distance between the two roots, a random number between 100 and 300), the height `h` of the jump (y coordinate of the vertex, a random number between 50 and 150) and the horizontal middle `m` of the jump (x coordinate of the vertex, a random number between 0 and the screen width). As a consequence, I also know the two roots of the equation.

Having this variables, how do I get the coefficients `a`, `b` and `c`?

[image: definitions of w, h and m]

Comment: Use the vertex form of the quadratic function $$y=a(x-h)^2+k,$$ where $a$ is the dilation constant and $(h,k)$ are the coordinates of the vertex.  Then expand.

Comment: @AndrewChin How do I expand if I don't know a?

Comment: You have a root.  Its coordinates are $(x,y)=(x_1,0)$.  Plug it in and \solve for $a$.

Comment: @AndrewChin Of course! Thank you very much!